# visual studio 2022 shows "greater than or equal"-sign (and <=, !=, ==) as one glyph instead of two separate characters

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I noticed in my Visual Studio 2022 with font 'cascadia code' that very recently (I noticed yesterday) that the >= and <= and != are now shown as 1 glyph.

[image]

It's both on my windows server 2016 machine as on my windows 2011 machine.

I've seen that in presentations before, and always thought it was very annoying, but now it's on my pc too!

I can't find any setting though to turn it off?

Answer (score 4):

Many of us like the ligature support, as it helps to clearly read the multi-character glyphs used in many programming languages.

However it is not for everyone.

Many ligature fonts are derived from other monospaces fonts without ligature. Eg. Fira Code is derived from Fira Mono, so use the latter.

In the case of Cascadia Code, the releases also include Cascadia Mono, and that removes the ligature. You'll need to go to the [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases/tag/v2111.01) and manually download & install the ttf files for the mono version. (Note the …PL versions add Powerline Glphs).

Some editors (eg. VS Code) do have options to switch off ligatures and control stylistic sets), but not VS itself.

Comment: Does anyone know if a ticket has been submitted for this with Microsoft?